# Recurion is not terminated

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have a following problem. My aim is to implement function that returns *Char* the *n* number of times

```
GHCi> nTimes 42 3
[42,42,42]
GHCi> nTimes 'z' 5
"zzzzz"
```

I have implemented such solution but recursion does not end

```
nTimes:: a -> Int -> [a]
nTimes a n = a : nTimes a (n-1)
```

And function just returs an unstoppable number **Chars**
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to stop a recursion, you need a *base case*. A case that will not make recursive calls again. Your `nTimes` however does not have a base case. Why would `nTimes 'z' 0` be treated special? According to your program that is just a case like any other. It will prepend `a` to list, and make a recursive call with `nTimes a (-1)`.

You thus can implement a base case, for example with a *guard*:

```
nTimes:: a -> Int -> [a]
nTimes a n
    | n <= 0 = []
    | otherwise = a : nTimes a (n-1)
```

So if `n` is less than or equal to `0`, we return an empty list. In the `otherwise` case (`n > 0`), we thus yield `a` and then recurse with `nTimes a (n-1)`.

If we test this with `nTimes 'z' 5` we get:

```
Prelude> nTimes 'z' 5
"zzzzz"
```

You here implemented a "flipped" version of the [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:replicate) function, so you can simply write this as `nTimes = flip replicate`.